# Get price from Price table if sales date falls between price_start_date and price_end_date in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a price regime table named `Price` and a sales table named `Sales` as shown below:

[image]

How do I write a `Measure` to get the applicable unit price from *Price* table based on Sales Date on *Sales* table if sales date falls between price start_date and price end_date in DAX Power BI?

Comment: Can you paste your tables as copiable text

Comment: SN PRODUCT UNIT PRICE START DATE END DATE
1 Fanta  10.08  01-Jan-23 04-Feb-23
2 Power Horse  20.90  04-Jan-23 07-Mar-23
3 Sprite  9.66  01-Feb-23 06-Mar-23
4 Fanta  12.10  05-Feb-23 04-Apr-23
5 Power Horse  21.50  07-Mar-23 09-Jun-23
6 Sprite  11.00  07-Mar-23 30-Jun-23

Comment: SN PRODUCT QUANTITY CUSTOMER NAME SALES DATE
1 Fanta  4   Customer A  01-Jan-23
2 Fanta  10   Customer B  04-Jan-23
3 Sprite  7   Customer B  01-Feb-23
4 Power Horse  12   Customer A  05-Feb-23
5 Power Horse  7   Customer C  07-Mar-23
6 Sprite  15   Customer A  07-Mar-23

Comment: Update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current price through Power Query when you load your data into Power BI.

To do so, the following steps are required:

1. Merge the PRICE TABLE into the SALES TABLE, on PRODUCT NAME.
2. Expand the relevant 3 columns - UNIT PRICE, START DATE and END DATE.
3. Create a conditional column that takes the UNIT PRICE if SALES DATE is between START DATE and END DATE if TRUE, and a dummy value if FALSE.
4. Filter the dummy value out of your new conditional column.
5. Clean up, by deleting the columns that are unnecessary now and sort the way it was.

You can use the following M code in your Advanced Editor:

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"PRODUCT"}, #"PRICE TABLE", {"PRODUCT"}, "PRICE TABLE", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded PRICE TABLE" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "PRICE TABLE", {"UNIT PRICE", "START DATE", "END DATE"}, {"UNIT PRICE", "START DATE", "END DATE"}),
#"Add CURRENT PRICE Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded PRICE TABLE", "CURRENT PRICE", each if [SALES DATE] >= [START DATE] and [SALES DATE] < [END DATE] then [UNIT PRICE] else -1),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Add CURRENT PRICE Column", each ([CURRENT PRICE] <> -1)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"START DATE", "END DATE", "CURRENT PRICE"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"SN", Order.Ascending}})
```

in
#"Sorted Rows"

2 important things to notice:

1. in this code example, #"Changed Type" is the last step made in Power Query on the SALES TABLE. Change it to your last step if needed.
2. You have an overlap of dates for 'Power Horse' on the 7/3/2023.
   I addresed that by doing (START DATE <= SALES DATE < END DATE).

Hope I have been helpful.
Goodluck!